# Hyperref Mailto with predefined object and content

Tags: hyperref

I use the following code to create hyperlinks to emails with predefined subject lines. Would it be possible to also add a predefined message in the body of the email?

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myemail[3]{%                %\newcommand\tpj@compose@mailto[3]{%
\edef\@tempa{mailto:#1?subject=#2 }%
\edef\@tempb{\expandafter\html@spaces\@tempa\@empty}%
\href{\@tempb}{#3}}

\catcode\%=11
\def\html@spaces#1 #2{#1%20\ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\html@spaces\fi#2}
\catcode\%=14
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\section{Test Email}

An email adress: \myemail{john.doe@doe.ab}{Subjekt}{Text in pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: RFC 2368 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) mentions a special option name `body' to specify the message body. Have you try that along with the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more about the [`mailto:`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol, rather than latex one, anyway the solution to your problem as simple as defining `\@tempa` the following way

```
\edef\@tempa{mailto:#1?body=Predefined Message&subject=#2 }%
```

Comment: Great, man! Thank you